# Scroll by mouse move not via wheel in mouse

Tags: mouse, resize, scrolling

I'm looking for somethingn which allows me to change **any event** with a mouse wheel to a mouse move. I imagine this should work like that:

I press and keep a key (or combination of keys) next move mouse (top-down). A reslut: I scroll a page. When I relase keys, mouse works like always - no scroll on move.

Maybe someone know how achive a similar feature?

Comment: You can try with `xinput`, `xinput --list-props` ,`xinput --set-prop`, etc https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101867/make-mouse-movements-scroll-when-the-middle-button-is-held-down

Comment: @EdiD, Unfortunately I don't have 'Evdev Wheel Emulation' property in `xinput --list-props` for my mouse (USB Optical Mouse). [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS]